# How to correctly indicate the destruction of objects for the has_many: through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I always wrote a similar code:

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images
  has_many :images,
           through: :posts_and_images,
           dependent: :destroy do
             def <<(image)
               super(Array(image) - proxy_association.owner.images)
             end
           end
end

class PostsAndImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images
  has_many :posts,
           through: :posts_and_images,
           dependent: :destroy
end
```

*I use code with `proxy_association` as needed. I think in this case it is not important. I just show it so that there is a complete picture.*

Now I decided to once again study the documentation and various examples that various people demonstrated on their blogs.

So I found a similar option (based on my previous code):

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images,
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :images,
           through: :posts_and_images do
             def <<(image)
               super(Array(image) - proxy_association.owner.images)
             end
           end
end

class PostsAndImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts_and_images,
           dependent: :destroy

  has_many :posts,
           through: :posts_and_images
end
```

For both examples, I ran a similar scenario when I deleted a post or image. And apparently both when they work the same way. At least at first glance, this is so.

Can you please explain to me the nuances of both examples? Which one is most preferable? What are the pros and cons of each of them?

Answer (score 0):

The `dependent destroy` being attached to which line is of importance:

In first case (weird though):

- Destruction of a post will execute but "its" images will be destroyed first automatically.
- Destruction of an image will execute but "its" posts will be destroyed first automatically.

In second case:

- Destruction of a post or image will destroy their post_and_image i.e. the model that was creating relation between them and the image or post itself being related `through` will not be touched.

I see huge difference. Do you see this? Try in rails console.

**Example:**

Post_A `has` 2 images: Image_A and Image_B

Post_B `has` 2 same images i.e. Image_A and Image_B.

Now try both of above and the results will be interesting.